# Rvest Pulls Empty Tables

Tags: r, dplyr, rvest

The site I use to scrape data has changed and I'm having issues pulling the data into table format. I used two different types of codes below trying to get the tables, but it is returning blanks instead of tables.

I'm a novice in regards to scraping and would appreciate the expertise of the group. Should I look for other solutions in rvest,  or try to learn a program like rSelenium?

https://www.pgatour.com/stats/detail/02675

**Scrape for Multiple Links**

```
library("dplyr")
library("purr")
library("rvest")

df23 <- expand.grid(
  stat_id = c("02568","02674", "02567", "02564", "101")  
) %>% 
  mutate(
    links = paste0(
      'https://www.pgatour.com/stats/detail/',
      stat_id
    )
  ) %>% 
  as_tibble()

#replaced tournament_id with stat_id
get_info <- function(link, stat_id){
  data <- link %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_table() %>%
    .[[2]] 
}

test_main_stats <- df23 %>%
  mutate(tables = map2(links, stat_id, possibly(get_info, otherwise = tibble())))

test_main_stats <- test_main_stats %>% 
  unnest(everything())
```

**Alternative Code**

```
url <- read_html("https://www.pgatour.com/stats/detail/02568")
test1 <- url %>%
  html_nodes(".css-8atqhb") %>%
  html_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses javascript to create the table, so rvest will not directly work.  But if one examines the page's source code, all of the data is stored in JSON format in a "<script>" node.

This code finds that node and converts from JSON to a list.  The variable is the main table but there is a wealth of other information contained in the JSON data struture.

```
#read page
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("https://www.pgatour.com/stats/detail/02675")

#find the script with the correct id tage, strip the html code
datascript <- page %>% html_elements(xpath = ".//script[@id='__NEXT_DATA__']") %>% html_text()

#convert from JSON 
output <- jsonlite::fromJSON(datascript)
#explore the output
str(output)

#get the main table 
answer <-output$props$pageProps$statDetails$rows
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e - I had no idea this was in JSON format, but it's amazing to see the volume of data you were able to pull in such a concise form of code. I'm going to watch some videos on web scraping json data to learn how to extract all the info!

Comment: The output variable is a series of nested lists.  It is just a matter of drilling down one layer at a time

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e - The output variable seems to only allow certain lists. If I keep digging, do you think there will be a way to customize for year and tournament? The json data states the variable_ids for everything, but there are not lists assoicated with them.  By changing the stat_id at the end of the url - I'm getting lists for that specific stat which is very helpful.

Comment: Regardless, this has been very enlightening in regards to scraping as it seems the way modern sites operate.